# C++ Get the return value from a threaded function later

Tags: c++, multithreading, return, future

Is it possible to not wait for a return value from a threaded function? Such as checking later if the value ever returned and do something else while that function is executing? I mean it's not really multi-threading if you have to wait for the function to return because you can just straight up call the function then.

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>

int func_1(int x)
{ 
    return x; //Assume this takes several seconds to complete
}

int main()
{
      auto future = std::async(func_1, 2);

      int number = future.get(); //Whole program waits for this

      //More code later

      while(!number) //Check if number ever returned?
      {
            //Wait for it or assume some error/default
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Whole program waits for this"* Of course it does, you explicitly told it too. Just don't `get` the result before you need it. Read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Comment: You might explicitly use the launch type `std::async( std::launch::async, ... )` otherwise it is not ensured the function runs in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requesting the result immediately rather than doing something else and then getting the result when you need it. If you do this:

```
int main()
{
      auto future = std::async(func_1, 2);          

      //More code later

      int number = future.get(); //Whole program waits for this

      // Do something with number

      return 0;
}
```

Then you can do something else in the `More code later` bit and then block when you need the result by calling `get()`.

Alternatively you can poll to see if the value is available using either [wait_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) or [wait_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until) and do something if the result is not ready.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the future is ready by calling [`future::wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) with zero timeout and check if the returned value is equal to `future_status::ready`.

Btw: `std::async` returns special futures and you should consider if you really want to use it. More detailed info: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html

Comment: Ah my bad. I seemed to misunderstood how future works. So it executes the thread and keeps the answer in the background until you fetch it is that correct?

Comment: Pretty much, except it doesn't necessarily have to execute in another thread (it could be deferred in the same thread, for example in the case where the computation is fairly expensive but not always needed)